# What determines the order of attributes from tag helper functions?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm an HTML designer but a Rails beginner free climbing my way up Michael Hartl's tutorial. One question that is probably irrelevant but is still bugging me is the order of attributes in the tags generated from helper functions. Example:

```
<%= image_tag "foo.jpg", alt: "bar" %>
```

Written this way, it outputs this HTML:

```
<img alt="bar" src="foo.jpg" />
```

I can see that the tags render fine and everything resolves in the browser. Does it matter for some other reason that the `alt` attribute appears before `src`? What determines that, is it just alphabetical by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between

```
<img alt="bar" src="foo.jpg" />
```

Or

```
<img src="foo.jpg" alt="bar" />
```

The order of your attributes doesn't matter - it's probably just the way Rails constructs it. What does matter is ease of understanding for you/other developers who might read the code.

**See also**: [Is there a standardized practice for ordering attributes in HTML tags?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/305329/is-there-a-standardized-practice-for-ordering-attributes-in-html-tags)

> *"There is no standard. Optimize for ease of understanding, and try to be consistent."*

Comment: Odds are that `image_tag(src, options)` ends up more or less doing `h = options.merge(src: src)` and then flattens the `h` hash into HTML attributes; that matches the observed order and is the easiest route to the resultant HTML. But yeah, it doesn't matter.